# Getting display driver for headless install of Kali

Tags: kali-linux, gpu, headless

I'm trying to get a display driver running for a headless install of Kali. (WSL on win10)
Using inxi, I can see there is no driver installed, basically because I'm running headless.

[image: inxi -Fxxxrz]

I've scoured the web to get a kernel mod so that I can recompile the kernel with that driver with no success.

The device is Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&SUBSYS_08311028&REV_00)

Without the driver, is there any way to get access to the GPU?

> hashcat -I

[image: Output from hashcat -I lists only the CPU]

Comment: based on this, it might not be possible except for purpose built machine learning applications.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue.
So even though the HD 630 supports OpenCL and Cuda, this is not the platform.
Intel GPU does not play with OpenCL on Linux. Only on windows.

> Intel has great OpenCL support on Windows, but no support on Linux. Intel's OpenCL SDK for Linux supports only CPU. Since hashcat is programmed on Linux (and afterwards cross-compiled for windows) there's no chance yet to getting this to work. GPUs are not magic go-fast devices. The microarchitecture and ISA have to be well-suited for the task at hand. As it stands, Intel GPUs have very minuscule raw compute power, and their ISA is not optimal for password cracking. Most modern-day CPUs with XOP or AVX2 support will be faster than an Intel GPU.

From: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#can_i_use_intel_gpus_they_support_opencl